# Folland Question 6.4 trouble with estimating norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

The question is as follows:

> If $1\leq p<r\leq \infty$, prove that $L^p+L^r$ is a Banach space with norm $\lVert f\rVert= \inf\{\lVert g\rVert_p+\lVert h\rVert_r\,|\, f=g+h\in L^p+L^r\}$, and prove that for $p<q<r$, the inclusion map $L^q\to L^p+L^r$ is continuous.

So, I managed to prove $\lVert \cdot\rVert$ really is a norm, and that the result is a Banach space with the given norm, but I'm having trouble with the continuity part. Given $f\in L^q$, I considered the set $A=\{x\in X\, | \, |f(x)|>1\}$, and the functions $f\cdot 1_A\in L^p$ and $f\cdot 1_{A^c}\in L^r$ (I've already shown these inclusions). What I'm having trouble with is estimating the norms appropriately. I found that (assuming $r<\infty$)
\begin{align}
\lVert f\rVert \leq \lVert f\cdot 1_A\rVert_p + \lVert f\cdot 1_{A^c}\rVert_r \leq \lVert f\cdot 1_A \rVert_q^{q/p} + \lVert f\cdot 1_{A^c} \rVert_q^{q/r}
\end{align}
From here, I'm not sure how to get an upper bound of the form $C\lVert f\rVert_q$, for some constant $C$. Note that I've seen [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3703553/568204), but I'm not sure how the last few estimates arise (particularly, why $|f\cdot 1_A|^p\leq |f\cdot 1_A|^q$ implies $\lVert f\cdot 1_A\rVert_p\leq \lVert f\cdot 1_A\rVert_q$, and likewise for the $r$ term). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Eparoh Unless I'm missing something completely obvious, no, $\lVert f\cdot 1_A\rVert_p = \left(\int|f\cdot 1_A|^p\right)^{1/p}$. The extra factor of $1/p$ makes it more complicated, which is why I have the term $\lVert f\cdot 1_A\rVert_q^{q/p}$

Comment: I deleted my answer because I just realized that.

Comment: You can take $f \in L^q$ such that $\lVert f\rVert_q=1$ then by your calculations $$\lVert f\rVert \leq \lVert f\cdot 1_A\rVert_p + \lVert f\cdot 1_{A^c}\rVert_r \leq \lVert f\cdot 1_A \rVert_q^{q/p} + \lVert f\cdot 1_{A^c} \rVert_q^{q/r} \leq 2
$$ Now, for any $f \in L^q$ you have that $$\left\lVert \dfrac{f}{\lVert f\rVert_q}\right\rVert \leq 2$$ and so $$\lVert f\rVert \leq 2\lVert f\rVert_q$$

Comment: @Eparoh Thank you, this is also a very simple estimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already quite far!

Recall that ~o show continuity of a linear map, you only need to
show that it is continuous at $0$

If you estimate
$\lVert f\cdot 1_A \rVert_q^{q/p} + \lVert f\cdot 1_{A^c} \rVert_q^{q/r}$
by
$\lVert f \rVert_q^{q/p} + \lVert f\rVert_q^{q/r}$,
then we have
$$
\| f \|_{L^p+L^r} \to 0
\quad\text{for}\; \|f\|\to0.
$$
Thus, the inclusion is continuous at $0$ and therefore continuous.

Comment: Thank you, this is very slick.