# Prove map $i: L^q \to L^p+L^r$ with $i(f)=f$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

I am trying to solve this problem:

> Let $q \in (p,r)$.
>
> For $f \in L^p(\mu)+L^r(\mu)$, define:
>
> $$||f||=\inf\{||f||_p+||h||_r : f=g+h, g\in L^p, h \in L^r\}$$
>
> Prove that the map:
>
> $$i: L^q \to L^p+L^r$$ $$i(f)=f$$
>
> is continuous.

Below is my attempt up to the point I got stuck on:

Let $\epsilon >0$ and let $f_0 \in L^q$. I wish to show that for all $f\in L^q$ such that $$||f-f_0||_q < \delta$$ we have:

$$||f-f_0|| < \epsilon$$

Since $L^q = L^p+L^r$ we know there exist $g_1, g_0 \in L^p$ and  $h_1, h_0 \in L^r$ s.t.: $f=g_1+h_1$ and $f_0=g_0+h_0$.

Since $g_1-g_0 \in L^p$ and $h_1-h_0 \in L^r$ we can see, by definition of the infimum, that:

$$||f-f_0|| \leq ||g_1-g_0||_p + ||h_1-h_0||_r$$

From here, I was hoping to somehow get an upper bound for the RHS in terms of $||f-f_0||_q$, but I cannot see a way to get this.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: what is the connection between $p$, $q$ and $r$ ?

Comment: Let me know if [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3947253) either answers your question or is helpful in any way.

Comment: @Surb right, added - sorry!

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer It's still not clear to me there why $$
\| f \|_{L^p+L^r} \to 0
\quad\text{for}\; \|f\|\to0.
$$ and why it's enough to check $f=0$. In any case, since I wouldn't have thought of the $f=0$ option, I would like to know if there's any way to continue what I started or at least fix somehow (?)

Comment: @Anon I see, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Thanks for the suggestion, though! Maybe it's the only way of solving this? Are you able to shed light on why the two items I noted earlier are correct?

Comment: @Anon Will think about it and get back to you.

Comment: @Anon Not able to figure it out, I am sure someone else will be able to be of help. Sorry about this.